# Do form parameter names need to be encoded when doing a POST?

Tags: python, forms, file-upload, http-post, urllib

**Quick version:** Do the names of parameters of "forms" being sent using the standard *multipart/form-data* encoding need to be encoded?

**Longer version:** The upload form on [1fichier.com](http://www.1fichier.com/en) (a service to upload large files) uses the following to specify the file parameter to upload:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" size="50" title="Select the files to upload" />
```

The name of the parameter is **file[]** (notice the brackets).

Using LiveHTTPHeaders I see that the parameter is sent like this (i.e. with brackets) when submitting the form in Firefox. However, for a [program](https://launchpad.net/nautilus-image-manipulator) I'm writing in Python, I am using the [poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/) module to be able to upload files using the standard *multipart/form-data* encoding. If I enter the parameter name with the brackets, it gets sent like this:

```
file%5B%5D
```

Internally, poster encodes the names of the parameters using this function:

```
def encode_and_quote(data):
    """If ``data`` is unicode, return urllib.quote_plus(data.encode("utf-8"))
    otherwise return urllib.quote_plus(data)"""
    if data is None:
        return None

    if isinstance(data, unicode):
        data = data.encode("utf-8")
    return urllib.quote_plus(data)
```

The [urllib.quote_plus](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) documentation says that this is only "required for quoting HTML form values when building up a query string to go into a URL". But here we're doing a POST, so the form values don't go in the url.

So, do they still need to be encoded, or is it an error of poster to be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 2388](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) covers multipart/form-data submissions.  Section 3 specifies that parameter names should be either ASCII or encoded as per [RFC 2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html).

So if your POST request is encoded as multipart/form-data (which poster is doing), then no, parameter names don't need to be encoded this way.  I suggest filing a bug with the author (ahem...), he might be willing to fix it in a future release ;)

A workaround is to set your MultipartParam's name attribute directly, e.g.

```
   p.name = 'file[]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Although in essence this question has been answered, I'm including some more details on how to dig through those RFCs.

[RFC 2388 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388#section-3) states that a Content-Disposition header is reqired. Non-ASCII data should be encoded using [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) even though that [looks like a conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13649258/1468366). [RFC 2183 section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2) describes the format of this Content-disposition header. The `name` fits in the general `parameter` rule of that grammar, but references [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) for that. [There in section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) you find that the right hand side of a `parameter` is either a `token` or a `quoted-string`. Neither production mentions any URL-encoded format for form names. But `[` and `]` are in `tspecials`, so they cannot be part of a `token`. So we get

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"        (correct)
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file[]          (invalid)
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file%5B%5D" (wrong name)
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file%5B%5D   (wrong name)
```

One more note for non-ASCII file names: the [current HTML 5 specification draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-html51-20130528/forms.html#multipart-form-data) requires not encoding them in a 7-bit safe manner, but instead transferring them in the encoding used throughout the request. [A question about non-ascii field names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20591599/1468366) is what brought me to look at this question of yours today.