# GET form parameter name is automatically encoded

Tags: html, forms

My simple GET request form's field names are automatically encoded somehow. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340618/do-form-parameter-names-need-to-be-encoded-when-doing-a-post) similar to mine but I am not using python, or sending that header. It's a simple form no javascript, php, python or whatever else. No form headers are sent either.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="views[]" value="print">
```

Looks like

```
&views%5B%5D=print
```

I can't seem to figure out how to not encode them. I need it to be an array on the other side.

Comment: See this answer on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160843/remove-5b5d-from-url-when-submitting-form

Comment: huh, so it's not possible then. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer on SO : [Remove %5B%5D from URL when submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160843/remove-5b5d-from-url-when-submitting-form)

%5B%5D are corresponding to []

[See this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

You can also see this post on how to pass array in GET forms :

[how to pass an array in GET in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098397/how-to-pass-an-array-in-get-in-php)